# Catch exception in Ktor-locations if non valid route parameter

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm new in kotlin world. So I have some problem.  I'm using ktor framework and try to use ktor-locations (https://ktor.io/servers/features/locations.html#route-classes)
And as example

```
@Location("/show/{id}")
data class Show(val id: Int)

routing {
    get<Show> { show ->
        call.respondText(show.id)
    }
}
```

Everything is good, when I try to get `/show/1`
But if route will be `/show/test` there is `NumberFormatException`, cause `DefaultConversionService` try to convert id to Int and can't do it. 
So my question is, how can I catch this exception and return Json with some error data. For example, if not using locations I can do smt like this

```
    routing {
        get("/{id}") {
            val id = call.parameters["id"]!!.toIntOrNull()
            call.respond(when (id) {
                null -> JsonResponse.failure(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest.value, "wrong id parameter")
                else -> JsonResponse.success(id)
            })
        }
    }
```

Thx for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a simple `try-catch` in order to catch the parsing exception which is thrown when a string can not be converted to an integer.

```
routing {
    get("/{id}") {
        val id = try {
            call.parameters["id"]?.toInt()
        } catch (e : NumberFormatException) {
            null
        }
        call.respond(when (id) {
            null -> HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            else -> "The value of the id is $id"
        })
    }
}
```

Other way of handling exception is to use `StatusPages` module:

```
install(StatusPages) {
    // catch NumberFormatException and send back HTTP code 400
    exception<NumberFormatException> { cause ->
        call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    }
}
```

This should work with using `Location` feature. Please note that `Location` is experimental above ktor version 1.0.

Comment: Sorry, but the question was how to do it with ktor-locations( in the first part of code), but you explain about second part. this part of code I showed just an example how can I do it without locations.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear at first. I did an update for my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thx Ervin, your second solution helped me) But why do you say, that locations is outdated? As I can see, now it's experimental feature, and  for example as you can see here (https://ktor.io/quickstart/migration/1.1.2.html) there is note:
" supported in locations out of the box "

Comment: You are right, it's experimental, not outdated. My mistake.